# 0x swap quote API not giving quote with SHIBA INU token

Tags: 0x

Tried 0x [swap quote API](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote) `GET /swap/v1/quote` to sell the SHIBA INU tokens but it is not working. Although working for other tokens like USDT, DAI, etc.

Query params I used:

1. With symbol `https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=ETH&sellToken=SHIB&sellAmount=85`

   Getting this:

   ```js
   {
   "code": 100,
   "reason": "Validation Failed",
   "validationErrors": [
       {
           "field": "sellToken",
           "code": 1004,
           "reason": "Could not find token `SHIB`"
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
2. With token address `https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=ETH&sellToken=0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE&sellAmount=85`

   Getting this:

   ```js
   {
   "code": 100,
   "reason": "Validation Failed",
   "validationErrors": [
       {
           "field": "sellAmount",
           "code": 1004,
           "reason": "INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY"
       }
   ]
   }
   ```

Also, tried swapping on Uniswap and it is showing a possible exchange. So, feel like something is wrong with 0x API because as per the doc, 0x considers all DEXs to find the best quote.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your sell amount is to low to the algorithm calculate a quote. Please note the sell amount is in base units as explained on the docs: https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote, SHIB is a token with 18 decimals so your quote for 85 SHIB should be with amount 85 000 000 000 000 000 000 resulting in an API call of

https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=ETH&sellToken=0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE&sellAmount=85000000000000000000

As you can see, now the API is able to generate a quote for that pair.

Comment: oh yeah, I am actually scalling the amount in my code but forgot to do it while trying with postman and shared it here. Nice catch and it worked with sellToken Address but still giving above error with sellToken symbol. Do you know why it is not working when symbol 'SHIB' is used instead of shiba inu address as my code uses symbol and not address.

Comment: Symbols are not supported for majority of tokens, I believe only ETH symbol works on this, so you need mandatory set the contract address.

Comment: Sure pal, thanks. I switched to addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, hence an answer.

I would strongly recommend switching to addresses in your app.

In general using token Symbols or Names is not a good practice, because it is trivial to create another token with the same data.

And when there are more than one, someone has to decide which one is the "correct" one, that could lead to errors, manipulation or the list being out of date.

The native token are an exception, as they (usually) do not have an address

> Native token such as "ETH" can be provided as a valid sellToken

https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote

Comment: Yeah, I switched to address as it makes more sense as it is something that uniquely defines the tokens rather than the name/symbol. Still, I will wait for the 0x team's response as I think they should either stop supporting Symbol as query values or give more insight into why their service is unable to find the SHIB token(there could be others as well). Curious to know this.